# How to read file/path containing tilde

Tags: go

The following code gives `ENOENT (2)` Do you know how to get stat of a file containing tilde?

```
file := "~/.zshrc"
fileStat, err := os.Stat(file)
if err != nil {
    return 0, err
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tilde is not something that the file system calls are able to interpret - it has a meaning only in shells like bash, which typically interprets it as `$HOME`. So you'll probably want to use `os.Getenv("HOME")` and then replace `~` with the result. Or, as suggested by Allon Guralnek in a comment, use [`os.UserHomeDir()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#UserHomeDir), which reads the appropriate environment variable depending on your OS.

Comment: `os.UserHomeDir()` might be a better choice since it's cross-platform.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the home directory of the current user using the os/user package.

Something like this will get you near what you want:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/user"
)

func main() {
    usr, err := user.Current()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(usr.HomeDir)

    file := usr.HomeDir + "/.zshrc"
    fileStat, err := os.Stat(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(fileStat)
}
```